# magento 2 custom calendar instead of core calendar

Tags: php, jquery-ui, magento, magento2, persian-calendar

I want to create jalaali calendar (persian calendar) instead of magento 
core calendar for admin and front pages .

for this purpose I've added these lines to my requirejs-config in my module :

```
   'map': {
       '*': {
          'mage/calendar' : 'MyNamespace_MyModule/js/persian_calendar',
         'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date' : 'MyNamespace_MyModule/js/form/element/date_form'

        }
    }
```

persian date and gregorian date are completely different and they have different years , months and days name . I want to show persian date to user but save date as gregorian format to database .

for sending gregorian date to server I changed **onShiftedValueChange** 
 function , I do this in my custom date_form :

```
onShiftedValueChange: function (shiftedValue) {
        var value,
            formattedValue,
            formattedValueUTC,
            momentValue;

        // this is very simple code that check if selected date is gregorian date or persian date  
        var englishYears = ["2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023", "2024", "2025", "2026",
            "2027", "2028", "2029", "2030", "۲۰۱۸", "۲۰۱۹", "۲۰۲۰", "۲۰۲۱", "۲۰۲۲", "۲۰۲۳", "۲۰۲۴",
            "۲۰۲۵", "۲۰۲۶", "۲۰۲۷", "۲۰۲۸", "۲۰۲۹", "۲۰۳۰"];
        var englishDate = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            if (shiftedValue.indexOf(englishYears[i]) > -1) {
                englishDate = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (shiftedValue) {

            // if selected date was persian,I converted it to equivalent gregorian format, for converting dates I used https://github.com/jalaali/moment-jalaali library 
            if (!englishDate) { 
                shiftedValue = jMoment.from(shiftedValue, 'fa', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').format(this.pickerDateTimeFormat);
            }

            // the rest codes are for magento itself
            momentValue = moment(shiftedValue, this.pickerDateTimeFormat);
            if (this.options.showsTime) {
                formattedValue = moment(momentValue).format(this.timezoneFormat);
                formattedValueUTC = moment.tz(formattedValue, this.storeTimeZone).tz('UTC');
                value = this.outputDateTimeToISO ?
                    formattedValueUTC.toISOString() :
                    formattedValueUTC.format(this.outputDateTimeFormat);
            } else {
                value = momentValue.format(this.outputDateFormat);
            }
        } else {
            value = '';
        }

        if (value !== this.value()) {
            this.value(value);
        }
    }
```

by these code equivalent gregorian date was sent to server correctly , but 
when I checking the value stored in database it's completely different and invalid , for example I sent this value : **4/14/2019 5:30 am** , but magento convert it to : **0010-08-10 05:30:00** !!

I think maybe the format date in my custom date_form is different from format date in magento form php code , cause this problem , because when I changed this.outputDateTimeFormat parameter to for example : "YYYY/DD/MM HH:mm" , stored value was changed and it got valid format value ( for example : "2023-08-10 05:30:00"  ) , but still it has different value from the value has sent and they aren't equivalent.

I don't know where magento check input date and change it to incorrect value .

Does anybody know where magento check date inputes and changing them ?
Or 
Does anyone have a completely different idea for this purpose ?